# Hyperledger Fabric: Endorsement vs. Proposal Response / Transaction Proposal vs. Endorsement Request

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

The 2018 hyperledger - fabric [publication](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.10228) uses the following terms interchangably

Endorsement vs. (Transaction) Proposal Response

Transaction Proposal vs. Endorsement Request

Are they the same?

In other words, is Endorsement the same as (Transaction) Proposal Response?

Is Transaction Proposal the same as Endorsement Request?

Answer (score 0):

> is Endorsement the same as (Transaction) Proposal Response?

In Hyperledger Fabric, Transaction Proposal is a request to the endorser peers to simulate the transaction on the actual ledger and signing the read/write sets taken from the result. It doesn't actually means writing to the ledger. Its just a simulation. The response peers give back to the client for an **endorsement request** (**Transaction Proposal**) is the **Proposal response** that is used for transaction verification, validation and achieving consensus.

> Is Transaction Proposal the same as Endorsement Request?

Yes. These both terminologies are the same.